# navigation menu does not appear as i want

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a new website and struggles with my navigation menu. My problem appears only in full-screen width but I think that my (mobile-first-design-code) causing some error.

My problem is:

I want a drop-down menu. But when I'm hover the `<li>`-element which include the next `<ul>`-level that list emerges in the right of the `<li>`.

What should I do to get my next `<ul>` right down under my `<li>`?

Here is my CSS and HTML:

```
/* RESPONSIVE-MENU */
.slide-toggle{
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
}

ul.menu {
    width: 100%;
    background: #5EB22F;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.menu li  a{
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu li{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f9f9f9;
}
.menu li:last-child{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.menu li:first-child{
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.menu li:hover{
    background: #b7dfa0;
}
.menu ul ul{
    display: none;
}


/* FULL-SCREEN-MENU  */
.slide-toggle{
    display: none;
}
ul.menu{
    display: block;
    padding: 23px 0;
}
ul.menu li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    border: 0;
}
ul.menu ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
ul.menu li:hover > ul{
    display: inherit;
}
ul.menu ul li{
    min-width: 170px;
    float: none;
    display: list-item;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    background: #5EB22F;
}

    <div class="menu-start-container"><ul id="menu-start" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-19"><a href="#">start</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18"><a href="#">om oss</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-17"><a href="#">tjänster</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-16"><a href="#">jour</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-70" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-65 current_page_item menu-item-70"><a href="#">flytt</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-72" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-72"><a href="#">städning</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-71" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-71"><a href="#">bud</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-69" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-69"><a href="#">priser</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-75" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-75"><a href="#">offert</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-15"><a href="#">kontakta oss</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

Comment: please add your `HTML` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe giving the submenu a position absolute and the "parent-menu" a position relative, now you can position the sub-menu underneath the "parent-menu" by using margin-top: (height of the parent-menu).

edit:
Can you post the specific part of the HTML too?

edit 2:

To position it under the parent-li element you have to add position:relative; to the parent-li. Else the child-ul will ignore the parent-li.

Comment: Yes ofc :) - I've implemented it right now!
It's a wordpress-menu. Probably as you can se.

Comment: Thanks a lot!

I appreciates your help :)